# Is it possible to show mathematical symbols in the terminal?

Tags: terminal, fonts, unicode

I want to do some program that can help me to check scientific formulars via terminal. It is possible or not if i want to show mathematical symbols (e.g. integral, diff Greek's Alphabets) on Linux's terminal. And if not what is the best way to represent the mathematical symbols when you working on terminal?

Answer (score 3):

To display most mathematical symbols in your terminal you need a terminal that supports Unicode and and you need a font with the glyphs for those mathematical symbols. You need this in order to interpret and display the characters correctly.

[Ucs-fonts](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs-fonts.html) is an interesting font project that tries to cover a large range of character sets. It is an extension of the standard `-misc-fixed-*` font that is found on most Linux systems, and it is a bitmap font you can use in both X terminal emulators and in TTYs for displaying mathematical symbols or other things.

Here's an example:

[image: awesome, right?]

You can use `xfontsel` or similar tool to inspect bitmap fonts installed in your system. The ucs-font is identical to the `-misc-fixed-*` font, but has the encoding `ISO10646-1` in the last field.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as you have a Unicode compliant terminal (for example, urxvt), and a font with the desired glyphs. There is a fairly extensive list of glyphs you might desire on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode).

Comment: How about square root(with a long equation)? Can?

Comment: @terces907 Yes, Unicode contains the glyphs to do that.